# Need assistance regarding sorting NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` and on every index I have another `NSMutableArray` but of different length like 2, 3, 4. I want to sort main array that the inside array who have bigger length come on top.

Comment: Add the code you have tried to the question along with test data.

Comment: So, read the documentation for NSMutableArray.  What you need is there.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them using a descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"count" ascending:NO];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
```

The above code creates one sort descriptor on the property called `"count"` in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

//Create a sort descriptor based on count using NSSortDescriptor class as-

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"count" ascending:NO];
```

//& sort your main array using sort descriptor

```
[mainArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```